# dask.array caching of whole chunk

Tags: python, dask

I have some large 4-dimensional datasets (100 GB+), where I use `h5py` + `dask.array` to process and visualize them. For example the shape `(1024, 1024, 256, 256)`, with a chunk size of `(32, 32, 32, 32)`. Since the data is typically kept on a non-SSD hard drive, and is compressed, it takes a little while to get a whole chunk from the HDF5 file into a NumPy array.

When exploring the data, it is nice to be able to quickly navigate over the dataset. An example of this, on a small artificial HDF5 dataset:

```py
import dask.array as da
dask_array = da.zeros((100, 100, 100, 100), chunks=(50, 50, 100, 100), dtype="uint32")
dask_array.to_hdf5("test_data.hdf5", "/test_data", compression="lzf")
```

Now, lets say we want to explore the dataset by grabbing a single position in the two first dimensions, and the full image in the last two dimensions. By using `dask`'s opportunistic caching

```py
from time import time
import numpy as np
import h5py
import dask.array as da
from dask.cache import Cache
cache = Cache(1e9)
cache.register()

dask_array = da.from_array(h5py.File("test_data.hdf5")["/test_data"], chunks=(50, 50, 100, 100))

t0 = time()
np.array(dask_array[5, 2]) # Takes 0.25 seconds
print(time() - t0)

t0 = time()
# Grab a different index, which in the same chunk/block as the previous
np.array(dask_array[15, 2]) # Takes 0.25 seconds
print(time() - t0)

t0 = time()
# Grab the same index as the first one
np.array(dask_array[5, 2]) # Takes 0.002 seconds
print(time() - t0)
```

Thus, the opportunistic caching stores the specific position, but not the whole chunk. When navigating over the dataset, this introduces delays, as the whole chunk has to be loaded from the hard drive for each new position in the chunk. **Is there a way to get `dask` to automatically cache the whole chunk via opportunistic caching?**

---

I'm guessing it is possible to use `dask_array.persist`, with something like this:

```py
dask_chunk = dask_array[0:50, 0:50].persist()
np.array(dask_chunk[5, 2])
```

However, this requires a bit of extra "infrastructure" to keep track of the `dask_chunk`. Thus, some chunk/block wide opportunistic caching would be better.

Comment: Thank you for a very nice reproducible example! Will be curious to see if this is possible, but my understanding is that this is not possible to do out of the box with `dask.array`.